# Why soup can only find 9 address tag while there's 20+ on the page?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

req_headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
}

page = ""
URL = f"https://www.zillow.com/homes/for_rent/{page}?searchQueryState=%7B%22usersSearchTerm%22%3A%22Bellevue%2C%20WA%22%2C%22mapBounds%22%3A%7B%22west%22%3A-123.13943309374298%2C%22east%22%3A-121.8279401738211%2C%22south%22%3A47.26821859666085%2C%22north%22%3A47.80963458591329%7D%2C%22customRegionId%22%3A%2222f2163d3fX1-CR1ka7jxdpi3s1x_1eoo7f%22%2C%22isMapVisible%22%3Afalse%2C%22filterState%22%3A%7B%22price%22%3A%7B%22min%22%3A0%2C%22max%22%3A872627%7D%2C%22beds%22%3A%7B%22min%22%3A1%7D%2C%22fore%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22mp%22%3A%7B%22min%22%3A0%2C%22max%22%3A3000%7D%2C%22ah%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22auc%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22nc%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fr%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22fsbo%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22cmsn%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22fsba%22%3A%7B%22value%22%3Afalse%7D%7D%2C%22isListVisible%22%3Atrue%7D"

response = requests.get(URL, headers=req_headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
# page_links = soup.find_all(class_="PaginationNumberItem-c11n-8-81-1__sc-bnmlxt-0 gFGtrQ")

address = soup.find_all("address")
print (len(address))
for _ in address:
    print(_.text)
```

I'm trying to get all addresses in the page, by using soup.find_all("address"). There are over 20 address tags, but it only returns me 9 item.

Comment: When I use "View Source" it only shows 9 `<address>` tags.

Comment: If I open the webpage in chrome and inspect the elements, I can see all (20+) address tags. However, as you pointed out, if I print response.text and inspect, it indeed only have 9 address tags... Any idea on why this happens? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's using AJAX to add to the DOM dynamically. BS doesn't run JavaScript, it only gets what's in the initial HTML code. You have to use View Source to see what BS is processing, not the Elements inspector.